# Getting count of detail sections printed in Crystal Reports (multiple details sections)

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

So, I have a Crystal Report I am working on where the background image is set in the report and I have a fixed space for the Description section where I print my details sections. A subreport is used to align the text over this section in the image. Basically, the customer wants me to use all seven lines in the Description (the subreport), then when the seven lines are used, a second page will print (same background image) and the lines will continue in the same description area.

The problem is that I now have to have multiple details sections. The report was already built to overflow to the second page using a counter of rows returned (if > 7 then the next page would be used). This worked with one details section. But now I have to print multiple fields of data across 2-4 lines.

So what I need is a count of details sections printed to make this work, since I have details a, details b, details c, details d, and details e.

Does Crystal have an easy way to count how many details sections are printed per record, not just how many records are printed?

Answer (score 1):

create a local variable in detail section and increment it and then reset at the start of group footer or report footer.

intialise the varialbe create a formula `@Ini`

```
Shared Numbervar count:=0;  //place in header
```

Increment the variable, create a formula `@Count`

```
Shared Numbervar count;   // place in details
count:=count+1;
count
```

Reset the variable `@reset`

```
Shared Numbervar count;  // place in footer
count:=0
```

Comment: This sounds way easier than some of the other things I was considering. But for some reason, the counter is not incrementing. I placed ini formula in the header, count formula in each details section (a,b,c,d) and reset in the footer. When I print count on the report it still says 1 in details a, b, c, d, so it doesn't seem to be incrementing for each details section, only per record?

Comment: Have you used shared or local variable

Comment: It's a shared variable. I created the formula fields ini, count, and reset like you did and copied and pasted the variable declaration you wrote.

Comment: I ended up having to use unpivot to return the columns as rows in the details section for Crystal to do this because of time constraints at work. Thank you for the help though.